# using the ln(x) function to justify a lot of rules

Tags: calculus

I use $e^{\ln(f(x))} = f(x)$ to justify a lot of rules, including $\lim_{\ x \to\ 0} [g(x)]^{f(x)}
 $ to be indeterminate for when both tend to 0. (for L'Hospital) And I also use this to simplify a lot of differentiation.

now my question is; is this dangerous? Should I not be doing this? When does this little 'trick' not really hold up?

Comment: I was just wondering where I should 'watch out' as sometimes this makes questions -really- easy, instead of doing it the normal way.

Comment: After all, $a^b:=e^{b\ln a}$ is the calculus way of defining $a^b$ for $a>0$ (which differs from the algebraist's definition that works also for $a=0, b\ge0$, but has other drawbacks when $b\notin \mathbb Z$).

Comment: It may get you in trouble if $f(x)\le0$ for some $x$ under consideration.

Comment: What do you mean with "the normal way"?

Comment: well things such as remembering certain cases and L'H and derivatives of certain equations. I usually just this method to compute them as it makes it easier. at least ofr me. I have notice that limits change when applying ln. from $x\to 0$ to $x \to 0^+$ for example.